# Complie framework only for armv7?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, armv7, armv6

Hi i have an App that supports armv6/armv7 architecture

My Problem is i have .framework file that was only available for armv7.

My Question is: How i can set the .framework file to compile only for arm7 architecture. I will support both architectures armv6/armv7 it is no option to set the architecture only to armv7

My Error message at the moment is:

ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice: $(PROJECT_DIR)
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You understand that armv6 is for iPhone 3G and older phones, and that the releases running on those are now two years old? How many 3G phones do you think are still working at all (I'd guess not many). What version of iOS does that framework support? If 4.3 its not going to run on a iPhone 3 phone anyway.

Comment: Yes i know armv6 is for iPhone 3G but i would not set the minimum target to iOS 4.3 and when minimum target is lower than 4.3 i must add armv6

Comment: And you must also not use the framework/library here but find another option. Why not make life easier for yourself and set it to 4.3. Our company looked at people connecting to our site from the web, 99% were iOS 4.3 or newer.

Comment: i said to set the target to 4.3 that is no option for me

Comment: I said you have to find another option, as there is no conversion utility that takes armv7 code and converts it to armv6 (that I ever heard of.)

Comment: then you should drop the framework off or you have to write the `armv6` version of the desired framework, if you wan to keep both architectures. it is simple. :)

Comment: So i have found the solution.
1. remove the framework from Build Phases
2. go to Build Settigns and search other linker flags
3. add there bouth architetures 
4. add at armv7 -framework [frameworkName]
5. add #ifdef _ARM_ARCH_7 to your code of the framework
6. yay it works